# Question on geometric measure theory

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

I want to know the following is well-known or not:

Let X be a metric space with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$. 
Then for any $\beta < \alpha$, 
X contains a closed subset whose Hausdorff dimension is $\beta$.

Comment: The empty set works, as does a 1-point set.

Comment: (unless the space itself has one point, in which case only the empty set works).

Comment: (unless you consider the dimension of the empty set to be undefined, in which case a one point set is a counterexample to the claim).

Comment: @Igor: I don't see how what you say implies, for instance, the existence of a subset of $[0,1]$ of Hausdorff dimension say 1/2. 

Comment: For complete spaces $X$ this seems intuitively clear, but how about non-complete spaces? Does for example $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ have this property?

Comment: Answering my own question: Yes, $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ has this property.. by taking out an open set (union of open balls centered at the rational points) of Lebesgue measure less than $1$ we have a closed set of dimension $1$.

Comment: A counterexample when $\alpha=\infty$.  Let $X$ be uncountable with the discrete metric.  Then a subset has either dimension $\infty$ (if uncountable) or $0$ (if countable).  The only place finiteness of $\alpha$ is used in my answer is to get $X$ separable.

Answer (score 18):

Let's do the case of complete metric space.   Let $X$ be a complete metric space with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha < \infty$.  Then of course $X$ is separable, as well.

We use a result of Howroyd [2] (following Marstrand [1] who did the real line).  Let $0 < \beta < \alpha$.  Then $H^\beta(X) = \infty$, the $\beta$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.  By Howroyd's theorem ($H^\beta$ is semifinite), there is a Borel subset  $A \subset X$ with $0 < H^\beta(A) < \infty$.  Then since a finite Borel measure is regular, there is a Cantor set $B \subseteq A$ with $0 < H^\beta(B) < \infty$, so of course $B$ has Hausdorff dimension $\beta$.

1. J. M. Marstrand, "The dimension of Cartesian product sets." Proc. Cambridge, Philos. Soc. 50 (1954) 198--202
2. J. Howroyd, "On dimension and the existence of sets of finite positive Hausdorff measure." Proc. London Math. Soc. 70 (1995) 581--604

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not know where you use the finitness assumption of \alpha in your argument. The finiteness seems to be needed only for \beta. If it is possible, would you please tell me which statement you used in Howroyd's paper?

Comment: Howroyd's first two pages can be viewed here: http://www.mendeley.com/research/dimension-existence-sets-finite-positive-hausdorff-measure/# (see the statement of Corollary 7).

Comment: I also note that Howroyd attributes the real & Euclidean cases to Besicovitch and Davies, not to Marstrand.